# C++ a program to calculate the greatest profit

Tags: c++

This program accepts input of the everyday prices of a good and then calculates the greatest profit. And the list of prices will end with -1.
for example, if I input 20,30,10,50,-1 , it means at the first day the good is $20,in the second day is $30,etc. The greatest profit output will be $40 since I could buy it on the third day at $10 and sell it in the fourth day at $50.

This is a school assignment and the teacher do not allow me to use array.
Now my program is fine except in this case e.g.
if I input 20 30 10, the greatest profit will be $(30-10) how could I fix it so if will not store the number after the maximum number e.g. 10 as the minimum number? Or any other codes to fulfil the purpose of my program?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int c(0), r(0), n1(0), min(0), max(0), l(0), s(0);

    cout << "Please enter the prices: ";

    while (n1 != -1) {
        cin >> n1;
        if (min == 0 && n1>0)
        {
            min = n1;
        }
        c++;
        if (n1 <= 0 && n1 != -1) { cout << "Invalid. Input again. Please make sure it's a positive number!" << endl; r++; }
        else {
            if (n1<min && n1 != -1) { min = n1; s++; }
            if (n1 >= max && (c - r)>(s + 1)) { max = n1; l = c; }
            cout << c << s + 1 << l << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << max << min;
    cout << endl << "Largest amount earned: " << (max - min) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Have you worked out an algorithm yet for solving the problem without using arrays? If not, why not ask a question about working out an algorithm?

Comment: How do you sell for 30 on day two and buy for 10 on day three? Does your system allow [shorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_%28finance%29) or do you start off with one "good" in your possession?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply calculate maximum profit by using the lowest price from now and not in the future.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int lowestPrice = -1;
    int highestProfit = 0;
    int price, maxProfit;
    while (std::cin >> price) {
        if (price < 0) break;
        if (lowestPrice < 0 || price < lowestPrice) lowestPrice = price;
        maxProfit = price - lowestPrice;
        if (maxProfit > highestProfit) highestProfit = maxProfit;
    }
    std::cout << highestProfit << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! That's so much more efficient than mine !